# get the value "18.18181818181818" using dividing in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

how to get the value "18.18181818181818" from SQLSERVER

```
SELECT (2/11)*100
```

I userd this Code but it gives me 0 why ??

in the calculator it's giving me "18.18181818181818" !!

is there any missing thing in my code?

Comment: Without knowing which SQL server you're using, but probably `2/11` is casted as integer `0`. Try `2.0/11` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are getting a zero, because you are performing [integer math](http://sqlservercode.blogspot.com/2006/07/integer-math-in-sql-server.html).

Try changing one of your integer constants to a [decimal constant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179899.aspx) and you will get what you expect:

```
SELECT 2./11*100 -- To simplify the expression, I removed the parentheses
```

Comment: I was going to suggest using CAST or CONVERT to force SQL Server to recognize the numbers as non-integral types, but your method does the same thing in a lot less code.  +1.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT (2.0/11)*100
```

Try that.  Putting the decimal there makes SQL Server use `decimal` datatype instead of `int` like you are seeing.

Answer (score 3):

SQL server is treating your numbers as INT's, you need to cast them as FLOAT's (or add decimal points to your numbers, I think that would fix it too).

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server is inferring the data types to be integers, and performing integer calculations - 2/11 == 0; 0 * 100 == 0

Had you done:

```
SELECT (2.0/11.0)*100
```

You'd have got it to infer floating point calculations and gotten a result of `18.181800`

Answer (score 2):

If you want control over the precision of your result, you should consider casting one of the numbers to a decimal:

```
SELECT CAST(2 AS DECIMAL(19,10))/11 * 100
```

Yields:

```
18.1818181818100
```